# Implement add-leaf, a Scheme procedure that takes in a tree instance t and a number x

Tags: tree, scheme

Implement add-leaf, a Scheme procedure that takes in a tree instance t and a number x.

This procedure will return a new tree where for each non-leaf node in the tree, append a new leaf with the label x to that node's branches. If the input tree is a leaf, the resulting tree is unchanged.

Hints:

append will merge the elements in two Scheme lists together. For example, `(append (list 1 2) (list 3 4))` results in `(1 2 3 4)`
map applies a procedure onto every item in a Scheme list. For example, `(map - (list 2 4))` results in `(-2 -4)`

You may find it useful to create a helper lambda function to pass in as the procedure to map
To create a tree with no branches, you must specify nil for its branches. For example, `(tree 5 nil)` is a leaf with `5`.

```
; Constructs tree given label and list of branches
(define (tree label branches)
  (if (null? tree)
      null
      (cons label branches)))

; Returns the label of the tree
(define (label t)
  (car t))

; Returns the list of branches of the given tree
(define (branches t)
  (cdr t))

; Returns #t if the given tree is a leaf, otherwise return #f
(define (is-leaf t)
  (null? (branches t)))
```

My code:

```
(define (add-leaf t x)
  (if (is-leaf t)
      null
      (begin
        (define mapped-branches
          (map (lambda (x) (append (list (x) (branches t))))))
        
        (tree mapped-branches
              (label (t))
              (append mapped-branches
                      (branches t) 
                      (add-leaf (branches t) x))))))
```

It complains that define: not allowed in an expression context in: `(define mapped-branches (map (lambda (x) (append (list (x) (branches t))))))`

Comment: There is no question in the question text. We have no idea what you want us to help you with :-/

Comment: the last paragraph

Comment: Yes, and we still don't know what you are struggling with when it comes to that. Btw. `define` inside a procedure can only be before the body expression. Here it is inside an `if` form and that won't work. You can use `let` there instead though.

Comment: The problem is to append a new leaf with the label x to that node's branches. The problem give me a structure to fill but i just can't figure it out.

Comment: You should edit you question with the code you have made, what you are supplying to the procedure, what you get as result (error/ wrong structure) and the expected result.

Comment: sorry my bad, i just fixed it

Comment: That is what I mentioned. `define` cannot be anywhere else than top level and before the first expression in procedures. It's not allowed in an `if`

Comment: You need to review the proper syntax in more detail. For instance, `(list (x) (branches t))` is not a meaningful thing to pass to `append`. (Start small.) Also, "create a helper lambda function to pass in as the procedure to map" does not mean "create a named helper function that passes a lambda function to map".

Comment: ^^^ "start small" +1.  this means write short functions and test them independently of each other, at the evaluation prompt, to make sure each is working as intended. then you can write "bigger" functions with confidence, using those "small" functions. --- you can just place that define right at the start of your procedure, as its first "statement".

Answer (score 2):

One way to develop procedures is to proceed step-by-step, writing ***examples***
and deriving a corresponding implementation at each step.

In this answer, examples will be written as comments, but in a Scheme-like form, eg:
`;(example: (add-leaf <args>) => <expected result>)`

Although not explicit in the question, it appears that `Tree` is a List with first element
Label and following elements its branches (which are Trees), ie:
`;; Tree is (List Label Tree ...)  [... indicates occurs 0 or more times]`

It's helpful to annotate definitions with their ***signature***
(types of arguments and result) and add simple examples:

```
(define nil (list))

(define (tree label branches) ;; Label ListOfTree -> Tree
  ;(example: (tree 5 nil) => (list 5) )
  (cons label branches))

(define L5  (tree 5 nil))

(define (label t) ;; Tree -> Label
  ;(example: (label L5) => 5 )
  (car t))

(define (branches t) ;; Tree -> ListOfTree
  ;(example: (branches L5) => nil )
  (cdr t))

(define (is-leaf t) ;; Tree -> Boolean
  ;(example: (is-leaf L5) => #t )
  (null? (branches t)))
```

"If the input tree is a leaf, the resulting tree is unchanged", so the first
example for `add-leaf` is:
`;(example: (add-leaf L5 99) => L5 )`

and so the first version of `add-leaf` is:

```
(define (add-leaf t x) ;; Tree Label -> Tree
  ;; *where t is a leaf* produce "unchanged tree"
  t)
```

For the next examples, consider a non-leaf tree (with branches) where the branches are *all leaves*:

```
(define T15                    (tree 15 (list L5))) ;; tree with 1 branch, a leaf
;(example: (add-leaf T15 6) => (tree 15 (list L5 (tree 6 nil))) )
(define T25                    (tree 25 (list L5 L5))) ;; tree with 2 leaf branches
;(example: (add-leaf T25 6) => (tree 25 (list L5 L5 (tree 6 nil))) )
```

now `add-leaf` has to append a new leaf to the branch list:

```
(define (add-leaf t x) ;; Tree Label -> Tree
  ;; *where (branches t) is a list of leaves*, "append a new leaf with the label x to that node's branches"
  (if (is-leaf t)
    t
    (tree (label t) (append (branches t) (list (tree x nil))))))
```

[In `(append (branches t) (list (tree x nil)))`, `(branches t)` is a *ListOfTree* and `(tree x nil)` is a *Tree*
(refer back to the signatures on the definitions), but
`append` produces a *List* from two argument *Lists*, hence the extra `list`]

Now examples where branches can be non-leaf trees:

```
(define L6 (tree 6 nil))
(define T15.5                    (tree 15.5 (list (tree 15 (list L5))    L5))) ;; tree with 2 branches: T15 and L5
;(example: (add-leaf T15.5 6) => (tree 15.5 (list (tree 15 (list L5 L6)) L5 L6)) )
; by using previous add-leaf, above example can be written:
;(example: (add-leaf T15.5 6) => (tree 15.5 (list (add-leaf T15 6)       L5 L6)) )
; and similarly:
(define T15.15                    (tree 15.15 (list T15              T15))) ;; tree with 2 branches: T15 and T15
;(example: (add-leaf T15.15 6) => (tree 15.15 (list (add-leaf T15 6) (add-leaf T15 6) L6)) )
```

Note that `(branches T15.15)` is `(list T15 T15)`, and `add-leaf` should produce a list of `(add-leaf T15 6)` elements.

So, bearing in mind the hints about `map` and a "helper function":

```
(define (add-leaf t x) ;; Tree Label -> Tree
  ;; produce "new tree where for each non-leaf node in the tree, append a new leaf with the label x to that node's branches"
  (define (add-leaf-to-branch b) ;; Tree -> Tree
    (if (is-leaf b)        ;; a leaf branch...
        b                  ;; ...is unchanged
        (add-leaf b x)))   ;; for non-leaf, "add-leaf"
  (if (is-leaf t)                               ;; as before...
      t                                         ;; ...
      (tree (label t) (append                   ;; ...
          (map add-leaf-to-branch (branches t)) ;; <- replaces "(branches t)"
          (list (tree x nil))))))               ;; as before
```

This can be simplified to:

```
(define (add-leaf t x) ;; Tree Label -> Tree
  ;; produce "new tree where for each non-leaf node in the tree, append a new leaf with the label x to that node's branches"
  (if (is-leaf t)
      t
      (tree (label t) (append
          (map (lambda (b) (add-leaf b x))
            (branches t))
          (list (tree x nil))))))
```

Now try it with a slightly more complex tree:

```
> (define T123.4. (tree 1 (list (tree 2 (list (tree 3 nil))) (tree 4 nil))))
> T123.4.
(1 (2 (3)) (4))
> (add-leaf T123.4. 5)
(1 (2 (3) (5)) (4) (5))
>
```

which is  `(tree 1 (list (tree 2 (list (tree 3 nil) L5)) (tree 4 nil) L5))` as required.

---

So examples can be good for developing a function incrementally, and as documentation.
*Checked examples*, where the function is evaluated and the result compared to the expected value,
could be more helpful.

To implement these, define `example:` as a *syntax extension* ("macro") as in the spoiler:

> `(meta define *examples* (list))`
>
>     `(define-syntax example:`
>       `(lambda (ex)`
>         `(set! *examples*`
>           `(cons (syntax-case ex (=>)`
>                   `[(example: e => r) #'(equal? e r) ])`
>             `*examples*))`
>         `#'(define _)))`
>
>     `(define-syntax check-examples`
>       `(lambda (_)`
>         `(syntax-case _ ()`
>           `` [(_) #`(begin ``
>                 `` #,@(map (lambda (ex) #`(assert #,ex)) ``
>                      `(reverse *examples*))`
>                    `(display "ok\n")) ])))`
>
>  [These definitions work in Chez Scheme, just copy and paste into repl or file;
>  other R6RS-based schemes may require changes]

Then the complete solution, using `example:` and `check-examples`, becomes:

```
(define nil (list))

(define (tree label branches) ;; Label ListOfTree -> Tree
  (example: (tree 5 nil) => (list 5) )
  (example: (tree 1 (list (tree 5 nil))) => (list 1 (list 5)) )
  (cons label branches))

(define (label t) ;; Tree -> Label
  (example: (label (tree 5 nil)) => 5 )
  (car t))

(define L5  (tree 5 nil))
(define T15 (tree 15 (list L5)))

(define (branches t) ;; Tree -> ListOfTree
  (example: (branches T15) => (list L5) )
  (cdr t))

(define (is-leaf t) ;; Tree -> Boolean
  (example: (is-leaf L5) => #t )
  (example: (is-leaf T15) => #f )
  (null? (branches t)))

(define L6 (tree 6 nil))

(define (add-leaf t x) ;; Tree Label -> Tree
  ;; produce "new tree where for each non-leaf node in the tree, append a new leaf with the label x to that node's branches"
  (example: (add-leaf L5 6)  => L5 )
  (example: (add-leaf T15 6) => (tree 15 (list L5 L6)) )
  (example: (add-leaf (tree 15.5 (list (tree 15 (list L5))    L5   ))  6)
                   => (tree 15.5 (list (tree 15 (list L5 L6)) L5 L6)) )
  (if (is-leaf t)
      t
      (tree (label t) (append
          (map (lambda (b) (add-leaf b x))
            (branches t))
          (list (tree x nil))))))

(define T123.4.
    (tree 1 (list (tree 2 (list (tree 3 nil)   )) (tree 4 nil))))
(example: (add-leaf T123.4. 5) =>
    (tree 1 (list (tree 2 (list (tree 3 nil) L5)) (tree 4 nil) L5)) )

(check-examples) ;; should display "ok"
```

Comment: `add-leaf` as shown produces a tree which may share some nodes with its argument; if the
interpretation of "new tree" is to be "constructed from fresh list structure", then change
`(if (is-leaf t) t ` to `(if (is-leaf t) (tree (label t) nil) `